# Assert same and equals in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, assertions

I have a function to be tested

```
fn doNothing(Student student) {
    //do some other operations here. but student is unmodified
    return student;
}
```

And my unit test is

```
var student = new Student("Deepak");
assertSame(student, doNothing(student));
```

But if someone calls a setter on the student in the source code (`student.setAge(22)`), the test wouldn't fail. Because the assertion only looks for the same object.

Other way of writing test case is

```
var student = new Student("Deepak");
assertEquals(student, doNothing(student));
```

But if someone changes the return in value in the source code to `new Student("Deepak")`, the test would still pass. Because it is equal to the value being asserted.

So in my test case should I assert both `same` and `equals` every time?

This is doable in the final assertion. However in the mocks, if I want to make sure right parameter is sent without any modifications, how would I do it? Because I can either do `eq(student)` or `same(student)`, but not both in the mocks.

Comment: I would contend that the behavior you're testing here does not make sense in the first place. Also, your last paragraph suggests that you're over-mocking. Too many things replaced by mocks, possibly, and very likely too specific in your mock setup.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that the object is the same and unchanged, the only way is to create a copy of the object first. Then you can check whether your original reference and the reference returned are the same, and you can check that the value of the object is the same as the value before the call - if you don't make a copy before the call, and the same reference is returned, then you call equals() for the same object, and it will always return true. To assert that the object is unchanged, you need to compare it to an older copy.

(Instead of copying the whole object, you could "get" all its properties and store their values into local variables before the call, and check that after the call, all properties are the same. This will give the wrong result if you forgot a property, or some internal state is tested by equals() but has no getter; on the other hand there might be irrelevant changes where equals() returns true even after actual changes that are not relevant).

PS. This is completely independent of unit testing. For example, an object might be read from a database, and you might want to write it back to the database if it is changed, and not otherwise. Or you might want to redraw the screen if it is changed, but not otherwise. Or show a "Save" button if the object is changed. You either need to keep track of everything that changes the object, or have a copy of the object - in this particular case you might be able to create another object from the same row in the database and compare with that.

PPS. Sometimes "equal" and "unchanged" are not the same. Let's say you record the last time that a database record was accessed. If you use the object, it's "last access time" is changed. But if that is the only change, then it's likely you consider it "equal" to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in having multiple assertions in one test. Provided that you are still testing one thing, not trying to test several different things in one test case.

But as gnasher729 has pointed out, your assertEquals probably won't do what you want it to, without taking a copy of the original student.